# Ettiquette guidelines for linking to MCVE etc

Tags: discussion

Tonight I have found several of the same comment on questions which have problems (big or small)

```
please read these: page1 page2 page3
```

The links are to How to ask / MCVE / On-topic

There's nothing overly rude about the comment but it tells the new users nothing, nor is it clear which page is most relevant, where the links go (at a glance) or why they are being asked to read them

The user does not flag the questions for closing (I'm not sure at what score they can do that)

Are there general guidelines on linking to those help pages that I could point the poster to? Is it OK to say something to the user in question?

Comment: "*it tells the new users nothing*" How do they tell users nothing? They explain the importance of having a clear question, doing their own research, providing a proper example that aids debugging, and so forth.

Comment: I meant the comment, not the pages it links to which are definitely helpful. The comment though doesn't tell them why they have to read those pages (ie that there is a problem with their question)

Comment: And their question lacks the information about how to answer it. Garbage in, garbage out. ;) More seriously, the point of posting links to those locations is to tell the OP to read them. That is why those pages *exist*. Taking time to explain exactly what they're doing wrong is taking time away from users who actually ask good questions.

Comment: I suppose that's true. I just thought as a new user I'd find that offputting. I used to see a lot of canned responses directing people to those pages that I assumed were generated by close votes. But I can't remember seeing one recently. I thought that might mean there were guidelines for how to broach the subject

Comment: I prefer to use the magic link `[mcve]` in these comments: "Please include a [mcve]". Sometimes followed by "with more information, maybe we can help".

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Had the comment in question been posted as an answer, you wouldn't be asking that ;) (Obviously, comments tend to be link-only to reduce clutter but I just thought it was funny considering how we treat link-only answers.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comment does tell the new user quite a lot, which is "RTFM", basically. All those links **are very relevant** for (new) users that want to continue participating here, and - *frankly speaking* - it's highly unlikely that the user in question has read those pages if someone actually saw the need to link to them.

What I'd recommend using instead of "page1 page2 page3" would be [Magic Links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). There are also quite good autocomment-userscripts with comment collections out there, enabling users - like me - who try to keep up with the trash incoming to leave **high-quality comments** without spending more than a few seconds on them.

---

In conclusion: You could - **nicely!** - point out to the user in question that he should consider using magic links, as those look nice, are self-explanatory, and take a lot less effort (*just writing `[MCVE]` vs. copying a link, and adding a hyper-link to a text-passage*).

Nicely because the user in question is actually **trying to keep the site free of low-quality questions** by pointing out general guidance to newer users. I don't see any reason one'd consider that comment "rude" or not helpful.

AFAIK there are no general guidelines regarding comments like this. We have the "Be Nice"-policy, but that's about it.

Comment: For completion a [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se/)